# Traffic Flow API - "Flow within Bounding Box" returning duplicate objects

Tags: here-api

Since Nov 30th the Traffic API - Flow with bounding box periodically returns duplicate objects along with what looks like a negative error object.

```
SSS Collection
SS Array

Collection
LE  8.80955
SP  56.45
**SU    56.45**
FF  62.11
JF  0.82804

Collection
LE  0.31939
SP  -1
FF  -1
JF  10

Collection
LE  2.84245
SP  56.45
**SU    56.45**
FF  62.11
JF  0.82804
```

Does anyone else see this or know how to fix it?

Comment: Just tested this today and the -1 and duplicate objects are still appearing it started at 1200am on Nov 30 looking back at the logs.


'"LE": 0.31939,
"SP": -1,
"FF": -1,
"JF": 10'

If you test it with this: [https://developer.here.com/documentation/examples/rest/traffic/traffic-flow-bounding-box]

with Co-Ords 
51.3632,-0.8986;51.3569,-0.8880

Comment: Looks like the duplicates have stopped today 7th Dec 2020, will keep tracking and update to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Please use any of these URLs where bounding box is {51.5082,-0.1285;51.5062,-0.1265}, duplicate will not occur then:

https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.1/flow.json?bbox=51.5082%2C-0.1285%3B51.5062%2C-0.1265&apiKey=<API_KEY>

OR

https://traffic.api.here.com/traffic/6.1/flow.json?bbox=51.5082%2C-0.1285%3B51.5062%2C-0.1265&app_id=devportal-demo-20180625&app_code=<APP_CODE>

One of the returned object is :

CF": [
{
"TY": "TR",
"SP": 21.47,
"SU": 21.47,
"FF": 23,
"JF": 0,
"CN": 0.73
}
]

Comment: Thanks so basically replacing the "," with %2C (UTF8 encoding) in the HTTP request.